# Why is this thread in python not stopping?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, simplehttpserver

I am trying to setup a simple http server in python in a thread.

```
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/shutdown':
            print 'Got shutdown request'
            self.server.running = False  
        self.send_response(200)

class Server():

  def __init__(self):
     self._http_server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8123), MyHandler)
     self._http_server.running = True
     self._http_server_thread = threading.Thread(target = self._run_http_server, name = 'serverthread')
     self._http_server_thread.start()


  def _run_http_server(self):
      print 'Server started'
      while( self._http_server.running ):
          self._http_server.handle_request()

      print 'Server finished serving'
      self._http_server.shutdown()


  def check_status(self):
      l = threading.enumerate()
      for i in l:
          print i.name


serv = Server()
print 'Sleeping for 20 seconds'
time.sleep(20)
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8123/shutdown')
print 'Finished sleeping'
serv.check()
```

My assumption is once the _run_http_server finishes running , the thread should stop running but it doesn't.I get this output but the thread keeps running. Can anyone point why the thread doesn't stop?

```
Server started
Sleeping for 20 seconds
Got shut down request
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2016 12:17:17] "GET /shutdown HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Server finished serving
Finished sleeping
MainThread
serverthread
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have your own request processing loop (instead of using `HTTPServer.serve_forever()`). Yet, you call `HTTPServer.shutdown()` whose job is to tell the `serve_forever()` loop to stop and wait until it does. Since `serve_forever()` wasn't even started, `shutdown()` never returns (it is actually waiting for `serve_forever()` to start and immediately stop). Removing the `self._http_server.shutdown()` line fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something.